# il2cpp file not available

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I developed an iOS game in Unity editor which `is also playable` in Unity editor and I did Build&Run the game in iOS (Xcode). The build is succeed but the game does not work properly. That is why I decided to debug my function and then I got the following errors in Xcode (`NOT IN UNITY`):

---

> NullReferenceException: A null value
>   was found where an object instance was
>   required.   at
>   BallScript.MobileControl () [0x00000]
>   in :0

---

> (Filename:
>   currently not available on il2cpp
>   Line: -1)

---

What is the reason to cause those errors and what can I do against them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the code in the `MobileControl` method in the `BallScript` class is trying to use a `null` value somewhere. I'd recommend debugging the code to better understand what is happening. You need to be using Unity 2018.2 or later to debug C# code on iOS. You can see directions about how to do that here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

Note that the `(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)` is benign. It is unrelated to the specific error in this case, and you can ignore it.

Comment: Wow! I did debugging the code and I found out that my animator of the ball was not correct. Thanks!